# Register dynamic Mapping (or delegate without explicitly resolving)

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dryioc

I have the following registrations prior to the one my question is about:

```
container.Register<ISettings>();
container.Register<Connection1>();
container.Register<Connection2>();
```

`Connection1` and `Connection2` both implement an the interface `IConnection`. To simplify my case `ISettings` just contains a property `UseConnection1`.

What I want is to register a mapping or delegate for service type `IConnection` that expects `ISettings` as a dependency and returns either `Connection1` or `Connection2` as its implementation type.

`RegisterMapping` itself does not have such capabilities due to the fact, that one can't use any depending services to specify the mapping dynamically.

`RegisterDelegate` on the other hand **has** the capabilities to get a specific depending service, but expects the user to return the implementation itself, not its type, like that:

```
container.RegisterDelegate<ISettings, IResolver, IConnection>((settings, resolver) =>
{
    var serviceType = settings.UseConnection1 ? typeof(Connection1) : typeof(Connection2);
    return resolver.Resolve<IConnection>(serviceType);
});
```

As seen, that implementation would be got from the `IResolver` which is far from perfect, as described in the [DryIoc wiki](https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/RegisterResolve.md#the-cure---registerdelegate-with-the-dependency-parameters).

What I wish to do is something like this:

```
container.RegisterSomething<IConnection>((ISettings settings) => settings.UseConnection1 ? typeof(Connection1) : typeof(Connection2));
```

Is this possible in any way with DryIoc?

Comment: You need to return `IConnection` instance - where do you want to get it from? (not just connection type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I agree with @steven that the runtime data should be treated with care and better be solved outside of DI. Especially, if it is mutable and being used as a condition.

Second, if unavoidable, I would've  used the factory delegate from the comments as the least surprise solution: `RegisterDelegate<ISettting, IConnection>(settings => /*connection construction*/)`.

Last, the heads-on answer would be the condition-based resolution and can be done with the condition setup:

[The live code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Eh7npk)

```cs
using System;
using DryIoc;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var container = new Container(); 
        container.Register<ISettings, Settings>(Reuse.Singleton);
        container.Register<IConnection, Connection1>(setup: Setup.With(condition: r => r.Container.Resolve<ISettings>().UseConnection1));
        container.Register<IConnection, Connection2>(setup: Setup.With(condition: r => r.Container.Resolve<ISettings>().UseConnection1 == false));
        
        var settings = container.Resolve<ISettings>();
        settings.UseConnection1 = true;
        var conn1 = container.Resolve<IConnection>();
        Console.WriteLine(conn1.GetType());
        
        settings.UseConnection1 = false;
        var conn2 = container.Resolve<IConnection>();
        Console.WriteLine(conn2.GetType());
    }
    
    public interface ISettings
    {
        bool UseConnection1 { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Settings : ISettings { public bool UseConnection1 { get; set; } }

    public interface IConnection {}
    public class Connection1 : IConnection {}
    public class Connection2 : IConnection {}
}
```

#### Update:

There is another option closer to what you have originally imagined:

```cs
container.Register<IConnection>(made: Made.Of(r =>
    r.Container.Resolve<ISettings>().UseConnection1 ? typeof(Connection1) : typeof(Connection2)));
```

Comment: Yeah, that was the way I did it prior to this post (with conditions), but I thought maybe there'd be a better way to do this. But comparing both variants (1. RegisterDelegate with ISettings, Connection1 and Connection2 as dependencies and 2. Register with condition) what would be the "best", in regards to code smell, etc.? If such a decision can even be made.

Comment: As I said in the answer, I would go with `RegisterDelegate` as a something you can put breakpoint into or with the `Made.Of` option.

Answer (score 2):

The use of runtime data (i.e. `Settings.UseConnection1`) during object construction leads to the [runtime-data DI code smell](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/), which is something you should strive to prevent. Also, the injection of both dependencies should not pose any performance problems as the creation of objects should be fast and reliable, because [injection constructors should be simple](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/).

Instead, try using a proxy, e.g.

```cs
public class ProxyConnection : IConnection
{
    private readonly ISettings Settings;
    private readonly Connection1 Con1;
    private readonly Connection2 Con2;

    public ProxyConnection(ISettings settings, Connection1 con1, Connection2 con2)
    {
        Settings = settings;
        Con1 = con1;
        Con2 = con2;
    }

    private IConnection Connection => Settings.UseConnection1 ? Con1 : Con2;

    // Implement IConnection methods here, e.g.
    void IConnection.Open() => Connection.Open();
}

// Or use C# 9 to do the same but with less code:
public record ProxyConnection(ISettings Settings, Connection1 Con1, Connection2 Con2)
    : IConnection
{
    private IConnection Connection => Settings.UseConnection1 ? Con1 : Con2;

    // Implement IConnection methods here, e.g.
    void IConnection.Open() => Connection.Open();
}
```

Now you can register your types as follows:

```cs
container.Register<ISettings>();
container.Register<Connection1>();
container.Register<Connection2>();
container.Register<IConnection, ProxyConnection>();
```

If, however, the `Settings` is loaded just once at application startup and doesn't change, there is no need to be able to switch between implementations at runtime, and you can reduce your registrations to the following:

```cs
if (settings.UseConnection1)
{
   container.Register<IConnection, Connection1>(); 
}
else
{
   container.Register<IConnection, Connection2>(); 
}
```

In that case there is no need for having the proxy class.

Comment: But in that case both Connections would be resolved, even though only one of them is really necessary. That case could even be done without a proxy just by using the RegisterDelegate: `container.RegisterDelegate<ConnectionSettings, Connection1, Connection2, IConnection>((settings, con1, con2) => settings.UseConnection1 ? con1 : con2)`. But also in this case, as written before, both Connections are resolved first, even though one would suffice. So it would be great to return only the type of the implementation that I want and than only that type would be resolved.

Comment: And yes, the resolving could be kind of "fixed" by using Func or Lazy instead of the actual Connections, like so: `container.RegisterDelegate<ConnectionSettings, Func<Connection1>, Func<Connection2>, IConnection>((settings, con1, con2) => { var createConnection = settings.UseConnection1 ? con1 : con2; return createConnection(); })`, but that is really ugly. So as written above: Just returning the type I want get resolved would be perfect.

Comment: If resolving both `Connection1` and `Connection2` poses a (performance) problem, it likely means that your injection constructors are not simple, while [they should be](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/).

Comment: You should prevent the use of runtime data during object resolution. In case `Settings.UseConnection1` can change during runtime (for instance because it queries the database or file system for this) it can cause issues. See [this article](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/runtime-data/) for more information. That's why I'm proposing the use of a proxy class.